# Two ISP's, Two Buildings, One Network?

Tags: networking, bridging

I currently have a setup with three buildings that are in 2 separate networks. As a result, there are no shared resources. I wish to change that by connecting two of the buildings via a Wireless Bridge. (See Attached Diagram).

I would like to connect them so that the resources can be shared, particularly the security cameras. Configuring the two ISP's to add redundancy, or even load balancing would be a nice to have but not required.

The goal is to keep it simple and without adding a lot of extra gear. Any suggestions?

Current Network with Proposed Bridge
[image]

Comment: How far away are the two buildings?

Comment: About 100 yds, but not easy to go Overhead or underground. Actually, I don't have an issue with the Wireless bridge. Rather, I am more interested in how the networks can be combined.

Comment: Check out this article:
[Merge Connections](https://superuser.com/questions/1546644/is-it-possible-to-merge-two-internet-connections-by-using-two-modems-and-connect)

Comment: Physically, network links across this distance isn't difficult. If there's basic line of sight you can use Litebeam (by Ubiquiti) or any of the several other products that do this. The networking side is beyond that though.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting the bridges directly to internal switches might not go well. Just like the fiber link, the wireless bridges will transport *all* packets – including DHCP requests. That is, every device will get two DHCP offers, one from the local router and one from the distant router, and will *hopefully* happen to pick the local one just because it arrives faster... but nothing guarantees that it will.

(On the other hand, such a connection has the slight advantage (or disadvantage) that other kinds of local device discovery will also work; e.g. distant printers will show up in the device list without manual configuration.)

Preferably, the two sites would be separate subnets connected by a router (assuming a router with support for more than one 'LAN' interface; the bridge at one end would connect to the '2nd LAN' port).

Answer (score -1):

A simple method would be to unify the two computers into one
virtual network across the internet.

Some possible products for that are
[Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/)
and
[ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by "Unify" the "two computers"? I have many computers and other devices, but have only shown a few here for illustration purposes. I do like simple though, so if you can provide more detail, I'm listening.

Comment: The virtual network behaves like a local network (LAN), so the devices seem to be connected to a common router and are directly accessible from each other. Try perhaps one such product to find if this suits your purpose.

Comment: This is a nonsense answer at best.